# How to read this gas rate

Tags: arithmetic

Please see attached image.

[image]

So does this mean its 32.7 cents per therm? Or 32.07 cents per therm? I'm very confused. Also why are natural gas rates marketed in this fractional way and not in whole numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\frac {7}{10}=0.7$$

so the gas rate is $32.7$ cents per therm. One reason why the image would be written that way is because writing $32^{7/10}$ requires less space and ink than writing $32.7$.